# How to start databricks cluster using web activity in azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

When I run the Web activity, it redirects this to login page and I get below as response from the web activity .. Suggestions please?

POST URL  : https://abc.azuredatabricks.net/2.0/clusters/start

Body : {"cluster_id":"1234-567890-stoke123"}

*{
    "Response": "\n\n\n\n    \n    \n    Databricks - Sign In\n    \n    \n    \n\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n",
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "x-databricks-reason-phrase": "OK",
        "vary": "Accept-Encoding;User-Agent",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache",
        "Date": "Sat, 01 Feb 2020 10:00:44 GMT",
        "Server": "databricks"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (North Central US)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": {
            "Managed": 0.016666666666666666
        }
    }
}*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292922/azure-data-factory-limit-the-number-of-databricks-pipeline-running-at-the-same

Comment: What did you pass in the headers? You need the bearer token.

Comment: Hi @simon_dmorias ... What to pass in the "Authorizarion" header - where to get the bearer token from .. any examples please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the bearer token in the header:

```
Authorization = Bearer yourtoken
```

Where "Authorization" is the key and "Bearer dapi1234567890" is the value.
See this article for how to generate a new token:

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication.html